# How to install Aspose.Words for Java using Gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, aspose.words

I am creating an application with Springboot that would merge fields and convert doc/docx to pdf. However, I am having an error in dependency when installing Aspose.Words for Java using Gradle. Is this the correct way on how to install it to my project? Here's what I added to my build.gradle file:

```
compile('com.aspose:aspose-words:20.5:jdk17')
```

Here's the error I got:

> Could not resolve: com.aspose:aspose-words:20.5

Comment: If you get an error, please provide the actual error in your question.

Comment: Which repositories did you define in your Gradle file? AFAIK, Aspose is a commercial product, so that library is unlikely to exist in a public Maven or Gradle repository, so you'd need to have it in a private repository and define that private repository in your build file or Gradle config.

Comment: That's all I did @MarkRotteveel . Can you provide a sample gradle config?

Comment: This can't be all you did, becasue that wouldn't be a syntactically valid build.gradle file. I don't use Aspose, so I can't possibly provide you with a Gradle config that would work, especially as I suspect you need to install that dependency in your own private, corporate repository to be able to use (and otherwise you need to contact Aspose for support).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify Aspose.Words repository

```
 maven { url 'http://repository.aspose.com/repo/' }
```

Please see 
https://repository.aspose.com/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/repo/com/aspose/aspose-words/20.5

Comment: It works, but it should be "https". Thanks.